# GetFourthColor suffers from constant triggering performance degradation

Tags: c#, vsto

```
     <toggleButton id="textButton2restricted" getLabel="getForthTag" getImage="GetFourthColor" onAction="PublicRestricted" getVisible="getvisiblerestricted" getPressed="GetPressedRestricted" />


     public void PublicRestricted(IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
            {
                documentService.SetActiveBook(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation);
                documentService.AddorUpdateWorkbookProperty("Tag", RegeditHelper.GetClassficationTag(4));
                RibbonInvalidateAndDeleteControl(control, pressed);
    
            }
  public Bitmap GetFourthColor(IRibbonControl control)
        {
            
            return ColorHelper.GetBitmapColor(RegeditHelper.GetClassficationTag(4));
        }

   public bool GetPressedRestricted(IRibbonControl control)
        {
            ribbon.InvalidateControl("textButtonpublic");
            ribbon.InvalidateControl("textButton2internal");
            ribbon.InvalidateControl("textButton2confidential");
             
            if (durum)
            {
              //  ribbon.Invalidate();
                return MetaDataControl(RegeditHelper.GetClassficationTag(4));
            }
            else
            {
              //  ribbon.InvalidateControl(control.Id);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Get Fourth Color method is constantly triggering. GetPressed Restricted method is triggered because the GetFourthColor method is triggered.
I only want it to trigger when I press the toggle buttons.
GetFourthColor suffers from constant triggering performance degradation

Answer (score 0):

The `getImage` callback from the Fluent UI has the following signature:

```
C#: IPictureDisp GetImage(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub GetImage(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef image)

C++: HRESULT GetImage([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] IPictureDisp ** ppdispImage)

Visual Basic: Function GetImage(control as IRibbonControl) as IPictureDisp
```

As you can see the handler should return an instance of the `IPictureDisp` interface, not `Bitmap`. See [Converting between IPictureDisp and System.Drawing.Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andreww/converting-between-ipicturedisp-and-system-drawing-image) for more information on how to convert one from another.

Also pay attention to the [Invalidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate?view=office-pia) and [InvalidateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol?view=office-pia) methods of the `IRibbonUI` interface which allows invalidating the cached values for all of the controls (or one) of the Ribbon user interface. Are there any other add-ins that could call these methods?

Comment: I clear the cache of other toggle buttons with the Invalidate control. this way i update toggle buttons

Comment: You need to use the `InvalidateControl` method instead of `Invalidate` one. Please remember that other add-ins can call these methods also.

Comment: Even if I use Invalidate, getImage(GetFourthColor) method is triggered in the same way